# Can User have more than one roles in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm developing a web application I want to use the role authentication to control different parts of the website accessibility. But my problem is say I implemented a upload and download functionality on one of the page and I want to have the ability to control a user whether they can either upload or download; or both. So, I'm not exactly sure if the role base authentication can support a user with more than one role to work the way I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, user can have multiple roles and can be check weather a user have particular role like..

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```